# VBA Code that will replace the cells displaying the numeric values (text type) with a blank?

Tags: excel, replace, numeric, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that gets data from another source.  One column has text names but a numeric value is presented if no name is available, the numeric value is also the text type.  Is there VBA Code that will replace the cells displaying the numeric values with a blank?

Answer (score 1):

This is for column **B**:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))
      If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then
         r.Clear
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that this will work, since OP stated, that the numeric value is stored as text.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost  I tested the code on a column in which all cells were formatted as *Text*

Comment: Ok. Thats good to know, that VBA will even detect numeric values, when they are stored as text!